# Angular - show checked value for Radio Button

Tags: angular

I've a popup and in that there is a list of items populating through *ngFor loop.
Everything working fine. Now what I want is, the first item remains selected when list first time show. Here is the code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="checkBox-holder" *ngFor="let mr of myReasons; let i = index">
        <div class="radio-btn reason-options">
            <input type="radio" id="reason-{{i}}" name="radio-group" [value]="mr"
                    [checked]="selectedReason === reason-{{0}}" (click)="selectedReason = mr" [(ngModel)]="mr.value">
            <label for="reason-{{i}}">{{mr}}</label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it's not working, and the radio button is showing as NOT checked.

Comment: Try` [checked]="i === 0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

In template html

```html
<input type="radio" id="reason-{{i}}" name="radio-group" [checked]="selectedReason === mr" (click)="selectedReason = mr" [(ngModel)]="mr.value">
```

In component.ts:

```js
constructor (){
selectedReason = myReasons[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove interpolation around value 0. Interpolation applies only to variables and not to constants.

```
selectedReason === reason-{{0}}
```

change this to

```
selectedReason === reason-0
```

and also make sure that you have selectedReason initialized as reason-0.

Comment: I've even directly passed the 0 value but that didn't work.

Comment: Probably, you didn't initialized selectedReason = reason-0 or your input values were not reason-0 reason-1 but they were 0, 1.

Comment: In above answer @Kaustubh is initializing it in constructor and checking selectedReason === mr which solves both problem.
Only point I was trying to make was use of interpolation was  wrong there and other two things are taken care by you.